# "ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments" error running `args = parser.parse_args()`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, argparse

I'm trying to reproduce [this BERTweet code](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/VinAIResearch/BERTweet?categoryPage=6#usage2).

I've run the following code in a Google Colab notebook:

```
!pip install fairseq
import fairseq
!pip install fastBPE
import fastBPE

# download the pre-trained BERTweet model zipped file
!wget https://public.vinai.io/BERTweet_base_fairseq.tar.gz

# unzip the pre-trained BERTweet model files
!tar -xzvf BERTweet_base_fairseq.tar.gz

!pip install transformers
import transformers

!wget https://public.vinai.io/BERTweet_base_transformers.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf BERTweet_base_transformers.tar.gz

import torch
import argparse
from transformers import RobertaConfig
from transformers import RobertaModel
from fairseq.data.encoders.fastbpe import fastBPE
from fairseq.data import Dictionary

# Load model
config = RobertaConfig.from_pretrained(
    "/content/BERTweet_base_transformers/config.json"
)
BERTweet = RobertaModel.from_pretrained(
    "/content/BERTweet_base_transformers/model.bin",
    config=config
)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--bpe-codes', 
    default="/content/BERTweet_base_transformers/bpe.codes",
    required=False,
    type=str,  
    help='path to fastBPE BPE'
)
```

...and this runs successfully.

I then tried to run:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

...which resulted in the following error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--bpe-codes BPE_CODES]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-96d3f587-5881-4520-9402-8ca07a3fdc75.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Here is what my file repository looks like in case this is useful info for debugging:

[image]

Why is the error being thrown and what do I need to change (and to what) to fix it?

Comment: [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is a parser for command-line options. What do you want to with it in colab?

Comment: Your parser is seeing a commandline value that's meant for the `kernel`, not your script.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. Is there a way I can change this so it works in Google Colab? I'm using GC because I want to train the model on a GPU as it's likely going to be too slow on my CPU.

Comment: Yes, instead of taking the code and pasting it into a cell in the notebook, save just the python part of it as a .py file, upload it to the Colab VM or your Google Drive, and call it from the command line. For example, if you call name the file `script.py`, then in a cell in Colab you’ll type `!script.py -<argument 1> -<argument 2>` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, `argparse` is intended to be called from within a script, not directly from the command line.

So instead of pasting the code into a cell in the notebook, save just the python part of it as a `.py` file, upload it to the Colab VM or your Google Drive, and call it from the command line. See [here](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#how-to-run-python-scripts-using-the-command-line) for details on making and calling such a script. You can also look at [this](https://github.com/jrjhealey/bioinfo-tools/blob/master/Genbank_slicer.py) example script.

For example, if you call name the file `script.py`, then in a cell in Colab you’ll type something like `!script.py -<argument 1> -<argument 2>` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes. It worked for me:

```
import sys
sys.argv=['']
del sys
args = parser.parse_args()
```